# How to impose a type constraint on the associated type of an associated type (e.g. Iterator::Item)?

Tags: rust, traits, type-constraints, associated-types

I'm trying to define a trait with an associated type. I also want the associated type to implement `Iterator` with its `Item` associated type implementing `AsRef<str>`.

While I know how to do it for a function or for a concrete `Iterator::Item` type, I can't come up with a clear and concise solution for the original case.

Thanks to the helpful error messages, my compiling solution is:

```
trait Note
where
    <<Self as Note>::FieldsIter as Iterator>::Item: AsRef<str>,
{
    type FieldsIter: Iterator;
    //other fields and methods omitted
}
```

The ugly `where` clause makes me think that there should be a better way.

This doesn't compile since `Item: AsRef<str>` is an illegal construction:

```
trait Note {
    type FieldsIter: Iterator<Item: AsRef<str>>;
    //other fields and methods omitted
}
```

This fails since `impl` is not allowed here:

```
trait Note {
    type FieldsIter: Iterator<Item = impl AsRef<str>>;
    //other fields and methods omitted
}
```

This doesn't compile since I want `Iterator::Item` to implement a certain trait, not to be a concrete type.

```
trait Note {
    type FieldsIter: Iterator<Item = AsRef<str>>;
    //other fields and methods omitted
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make one small improvement, but otherwise the current syntax for this is as you have discovered:

```
trait Note
where
    <Self::FieldsIter as Iterator>::Item: AsRef<str>,
{
    type FieldsIter: Iterator;
}
```

This is the disambiguated syntax, the only problem is there isn't yet a way to make the ambiguous version! [Rust issue #38078](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38078) is open to allow the `Foo::Bar::Baz` syntax.

[RFC 2289](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2289-associated-type-bounds.md) is also open as a way to improve this. With the RFC implemented, your second example should work:

```
trait Note {
    type FieldsIter: Iterator<Item: AsRef<str>>;
}
```

One way you can work around this now is similar to [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html). This introduces another associated type:

```
trait Note {
    type FieldsIter: Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;
    type Item: AsRef<str>;
}
```

I'm not a fan of this because it introduces types that at first look to be orthogonal to each other, but in the end are tightly related.